# How to access a function in a child class component from a stateless parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a redux-store with objects of initial values. And this store will get updated at a few places within the child component.

I created a stateless functional component as parent

```
const Parent = () => {
  const store = useSelector(state => state);
  const getInitState = () => {
    depends on store, it will return an object as initial state for child component
  }
  let initState = getInitState(); //it has to be let instead of const, it could be changed during useEffect
  
  useEffect(() => {
    some initialization on mount
  }, [])

  return ( // return is simplified here
    <Child initState={iniState} />
  )
}

export default Parent;
```

I have a class child component something like below

```
class Child extends Component {
  state = {
    componentState: this.props.initState
  }

  ....
}

export default Child;
```

I can't modify the child component It's a very complex component with many sub components which I dont handle.

Now I need to access `setState` function of child component from parent. Or I need to change the state of child from parent, is there a way to do that?

Yes, I understand a new design should be consider since it's anti-pattern, but I am just wondering if I can do it under current setting.

Thank you all in advance.

==============================================================

Edit: For whoever runs into the same problem, functional component does not support constructor. So I have included a breif correction to the answer.

Define parent as below

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

const Parent = () => {
  const childRef = useRef(null);

  return ( 
    <Child ref={childRef} />
  )
}

export default Parent;
```

Then you are able to use childRef.current to access all function from child component.

Comment: Try to lift your state up i.e change child from parent: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: Can you implement the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method in the child and simply pass it an updated `initState` prop? The alternative it lifting state... or coming up with a non-anti-pattern design for the child. Why are you duplicating the state?

Comment: Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using a [react Context](https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/context.html) , and set state in parent then the child consume state of parent (using react hooks would be so easy than class component)

but in your case as you mentiened (I wonder I can do it under current setting)

you can use [react `refs`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) :

first put ref prop in your rendered component tag then use it in parent to execute function that's declared inside child

as below :

inside parent component :

```
const Parent = () => {
  .
  .
  .
  constructor() {
     //create react ref for our component
     this.childComponent = React.createRef();
  }   

  callChildFunction() {
     // here using refs you can access function in you child refenrenced component
     this.childComponent.cuurent.doSomeUpdateStateStuff(newState);
  }
  
  return ( // return is simplified here
    <Child ref={this.childComponen} initState={iniState} />
  )
  ...
}
```

and your child :

```
class Child extends Component {
  state = {
    componentState: this.props.initState
  }
  

  doSomeUpdateStateStuff(state) {
     // stuff updating state callled from parent
  }
  ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will try it out tomorrow.

Comment: @user3685525 seems you're facing problem ?

Comment: Yes, my original difficulties was I can't have a constructor in a functional component, but your idea works. Thanks.

Comment: ah okey , in functional component , just refer it to a varible , example `let childComponent = React.createRef();` then refernce it in jsx without using this kyeword , 
if this help you could you accept the answer